# Script scheduled in TaskScheduler (with a .bat file) never completes

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

I've scheduled a batch file that has this command in a TaskScheduler **and it never completes**:

```
powershell -command "& 'C:\Test\CleanUp.ps1'"
```

The .ps1 file has a simple script that deletes files on different shares. The powershell script runs successfully when run in ISE or even the above mentioned command runs successfully when run at cmd prompt.

I've even tried the option below with the command and also searched a number of blogs but no luck.

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

The task is scheduled to run with a service account and I've setup a number of identical jobs the same way and they worked fine. I have powershell version 4.0.

*How do I get the job to complete?* (successfully or with a failure)

Comment: Check the eventlog and the task history for errors and warnings. Add debugging code to your script that logs status/progress information to a file or the eventlog. Nothing else we can tell you with this little information.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before and generally it turns out to be that, when running as a different user and/or with a different profile, the script hangs because it needs to prompt for input, e.g. a missing mandatory parameter, Get-Credential, or something like that.

I'll assume that you have run the command from an interactive shell running as the service account, as this could reveal whether there is something different about the service account profile, etc. that may interfere with the running of the script.

I'll also assume that you have tried setting up the scheduled task with your own account, under which you know the script will run correctly.

Next, look at some of the other command line options for `powershell.exe`:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847736.aspx

I'm not sure whether you'll get much mileage from the `-ExecutionPolicy` switch, as my experience is that people tend to set the policy to Unrestricted almost as soon as the server is commissioned and then never think about it again.

You might want to look at the `-NoProfile` switch, as that is something I see used quite often when calling PowerShell from a .bat file or directly in the task scheduler.

Notice the `-File` switch, which you might consider using instead of `-Command`.

Comment: I've tried scheduling the task with my creds and after starting the task manually, I see in the task manager, a powershell.exe and a cmd.exe show up and doesn't close by themselves. I've to kill cmd.exe and end the process tree and only then task stops (of course with a failure). I've tried -NoProfile option an it didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm. Are you able to confirm how far through the PS script the job is getting,e.g. by writing to a log file, as per @Ansgar's comment on the OP. At this point you need to demonstrate that your script is actually running through to completion and not getting stuck in a loop somewhere.

Comment: Does the script rely on being run from a certain location, e.g. from a specific folder? It may be that the default location/path that PowerShell opens in is different when you switch between users (although this wouldn't directly explain why it still failed running with your creds).